# Why do I need to use the helper method create_user() inside of a TestCase in Django?

Tags: python, django

This fails the test:

```
class LoginTest(TestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        self.user = User(username='test', password='test')
        self.user.save()
        login = self.client.login(username='test', password='test')
        self.assertTrue(login)
```

But this passes it:

```
class LoginTest(TestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', password='test')
        login = self.client.login(username='test', password='test')
        self.assertTrue(login)
```

Can anyone explain me why? Outside of the TestCase class it works.

EDIT: It was working outside of the TestCase because I was trying with an existent user. See falsetru answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `User.objects.create_user`, the password is saved as is (without being encrypted).

[`check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.check_password) (that is iternally used by `login`, `authenticate`, ...) expects that the password is encrypted.

And the final code should fail without using `User.objects.create_user`:

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> user = User(username='test', password='test')
>>> user.save()
>>> c.login(username='test', password='test')
False
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> authenticate(username='test', password='test') # => None
>>>
```

Use `User.objects.create_user`!

```
>>> user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='test2', password='test')
>>> c.login(username='test2', password='test')
True
>>> authenticate(username='test2', password='test')
<User: test2>
>>> user2.check_password('test')
True
```

Comment: Oh god, yes, my fault, I wrote the third code example by memory but when I tried it was using an already created username. Now everything is clear. I edit it to avoid confusions.

Thanks!